# onclick event with jquery load not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I have a web page that dynamically loads a html page in a div within this page.

This web page comes with a panel, header and navbar jquery containers. Within those some anchors are set.

The div used for loading the html pages dynamically, comes at first with a loaded html with some anchors. This page is set via jsp:include page="main.html".

All of the anchors have almost the same strcuture:

```
<a href="#top" onclick="$('#mainContainer').load('heatProduction.html');" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-search ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-inline">Search</a>
```

However, none of those are working. You click, it appears to do something but everything remains the same. As far as I can see the target html page is requested via http as shown in the developer tools.

I think this may be related to event delegation since after applying a workaround to load the complete web page for second time all anchors starts working. But if thats the case, I am not sure of the workaround to implement.

Here is the workaround that was applied:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
        var url_string = window.location.href;
        var url = new URL(url_string);
        var r = url.searchParams.get("r");
        if (r==null){
            window.location.href = "index.jsp?r=1";
        }   
</script>
```

Regards

Comment: Maybe you are not waiting for the document ready. Try assign an id to your href, and then, in JavaScript wait for $(document).ready(), inside add a listener for your href: $("#your_href").click() and on the click load the content inside mainContainer

Comment: Hi @LuisCabreraBenito I tried your suggestion adding the below code inside the javascript of index.jsp with no change on the behavior:` 
  $(document).ready(function(){                                        
                 $('#issue').click(function(){            
                      $('#mainContainer').load('main.html');                                         
                 });                                                                                                         
    });`

Comment: A big thing that I forgot to mention is that the whole page where the referred div and anchors are is created as well dynamically.